# How to count correct answer only one time if I attempt many time correctly?

Tags: javascript

I am counting the correct answer for total 5 questions. If I am going to re-attempt the same question and get correct again, I shouldn't count it as correct again. I am writing code using javascript.

my code is like this, but if I re attempt same question correctly, my total score will add again.

```
var score = 0;

question1.addEventListener("click", () => {

    var firstQuestion = confirm("Is 10 < 20?");

    if (firstQuestion == true){
        score += 1;
        document.getElementById("answerQuestion1").innerHTML = `Correct`;
        document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = `Your score is: ${score}`;
    }
    else{
        score = 0;
        document.getElementById("answerQuestion1").innerHTML = `Incorrect`;
        document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = `Your score is: ${score}`;
    }
});
```

Comment: you can use a flag, say on click one and if the answer is correct, increase flag to one.And to add up the score you condition  `if(flag!=0){score+=0} else{score+=1}`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var score = 0
var firstattempt=true

question1.addEventListener("click", () => {

var firstQuestion = confirm("Is 10 < 20?");

                if (firstQuestion == true && firstattempt)
                {
                    score += 1;
                    document.getElementById("answerQuestion1").innerHTML = `Correct`;
                    document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = `Your score is: ${score}`;
                }else
                {
                    score=0;
                    firstattempt=false
                    document.getElementById("answerQuestion1").innerHTML = `Incorrect`;
                    document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = `Your score is: ${score}`;
                }


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unbind event listener when correct, or hide, or disable.

```js
var score = 0; var q1fn;
question1.addEventListener("click", q1fn = () => {

  var firstQuestion = confirm("Is 10 < 20?");

  if (firstQuestion == true) {
     //hide button
//         question1.style.display="none";
     //disable button
    question1.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
     // or unbind event listener so it no longer responds
    question1.removeEventListener("click",q1fn);
    score += 1;
    document.getElementById("answerQuestion1").innerHTML = `Correct`;
    document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = `Your score is: ${score}`;
  } else {
    score = 0;
    document.getElementById("answerQuestion1").innerHTML = `Incorrect`;
    document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = `Your score is: ${score}`;
  }


});
```

```html
<button id="question1">q</button>

<div id="answerQuestion1"></div>
<div id="summary"></div>
```